# Flutter better_player Package Stop and Play Video using Controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I'm new with flutter and currently using **better_player: ^0.0.81** package.

Is there anyway to stop the video using a controller? Here is my code below

```
late BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController;
```

**Function**

```
_betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
  const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
    autoPlay: true,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
      enableOverflowMenu: false,
      showControlsOnInitialize: false,
      enableRetry: true,
      showControls: true,
    ),
  ),
  betterPlayerDataSource: BetterPlayerDataSource.file(videoPath),
);
```

**Widget**

```
  AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
       child: BetterPlayer(
                controller: _betterPlayerController,
       ),
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean pause and play, then just call it by using the controller.

```
eg: _betterPlayerController.pause();  or  _betterPlayerController.play();
```